# PHP - Getting Indirect modification of overload property has no effect when modifying object

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, overloading

I am loosing my mind here!
I'm getting this error when trying to do the following:

```
 $adGroups = $adSet->getAdGroups($fields)->getArrayCopy();
    BioCommandController::log("Syncing '{$adSet->{AdSetFields::NAME}}' groups: " . count($adGroups));
    foreach($adGroups as $adGroup) {

        echo "<pre>";
        if($adGroup->conversion_specs[0]){

            $adGroup->conversion_specs[0]['action_type'] = $adGroup->conversion_specs[0]['action.type'];
            unset($adGroup->conversion_specs[0]['action.type']);
```

I have the object $adGroups, this object comes from facebook.
I need to modify the $key **$adGroup->conversion_specs[0]['action.type']** to
**$adGroup->conversion_specs[0]['action_type']**
The reason is because i need to save this object on a mongoDB database, and it doesn't accept this key format!

I've tried to do the obivious, create the right key for the object and insert the content inside it, and then unset the key that i don't want, but it throws that error.

I'm really lost here, any solutions????

I've read several issues on this error but none of them helped me!
The extend ArrayObject solution doesn't work for me, because my classes already extend others (and it's from a framework, yii). So i don't want to do a huge jerry rick to extend it.

And i don't understand why this is not working, i've always done that and it used to work just fine, it's so off putting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why that was not working, but i've changed my approach and at leat was able to do what i needed:

```
 //We recreate the peace of the object that needs to be modified
            $newKey = $adGroup->conversion_specs[0];
            $data = $adGroup->conversion_specs[0]['action.type'];
            unset ($newKey['action.type']);
            $newKey['action_type'] = $data;
       $adGroup->conversion_specs = $newKey;
```